# Referencing Cell as Variable in Range().Select

Tags: excel, vba, range

I am copying and pasting data into blocks of cells which move down the spreadsheet in regular blocks for each brand - I am therefore trying to create a variable linked to Brand Number, but am receiving this error.

Hopefully a simple one, hoping somebody can help!

```
Dim StartCell1 As String
Dim BrandNumber As Integer
Dim DblQuote As String

StartCell1 = vbDblQuote + "B" + CStr((3 + (27 * (BrandNumber - 1)))) + vbDblQuote

BrandNumber = 1

Range(StartCell1).Select
```

> Run-time error '1004':
>     Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

Comment: check the value of `StartCell1`, if you add a line `Debug.Print StartCell1` before the line of `Range(StartCell1).Select` what do you get in the immediate window ? Also what is the value of `BrandNumber`, is it larger then 2 ?

Comment: You wont need the double quotes.  I think `B` and your number should be good in a string.  So your string will be `b3` not `"b3"`

Comment: Hi - Tried without the quotes didn't work, exactly the same issue and error! Thanks though

Shai Rado - Brand Number Starts at 1 (but multiplying 0 by 27 and adding 3 should be fine, right?)
And apologies, being new-ish to VBA error handling. I've tried the Debug.Print, I get the same error as it seems that it's simply jumping straight over the Debug.Print. 

Also I'm used to Python...where is the output console where I would see the Value?!

Thanks!

Comment: You should avoid using select. You can try with Range objects `Dim CopyRange As Range` and then `Set CopyRange = Range("A1:A100")` for example, so you could just `CopyRange.Copy Destination:=Range("A101")`

Comment: By the way, your `BrandNumber = 1` should go before the `StartCell1 =  `... Otherwise BrandNumber will be -1 and that will give you an error.

Comment: @ThomasGardner the output window is called Locals.  WHat is `vbDblQuote`

Comment: Your brandnumber not being set, will result in a -ve result, which translates to `""B-24""` using your code.  You need to get rid of the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim StartCell  As Range
Dim BrandNumber As Integer
BrandNumber = 1
set StartCell = Range("B" & (3 + (27 * (BrandNumber - 1))))
```

Excel will convert the number returned by (3 + (...   into a string automatically. 
I've created an object variable to point to startcell so you can just copy it to a destination in one line - this would copy it to A2 for example

```
StartCell.Copy Range("a2")
```

Never use Select  [How To Avoid using Select in VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba?rq=1)